# What does the LOST.DIR folder contain?

Tags: sd-card

Whats the use of LOST.DIR folder actually?
why does is automatically appear after every reboot?

Comment: [How can I recover the files in LOST.DIR on my SD card, and what are they?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/14555/981), [How to prevent Android from creating LOST.DIR on SD card?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/44959/981)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Lost.dir` is a ***system folder***. Its a place where the Android OS places files that were recovered **during a system boot up**.

[**lost.dir in android**](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=lost.dir%20in%20android)

---

**What is the folder for?**

> Its quite evident that there is no application named LOST.DIR
>   installed on your device. At times the folder's size can range in
>   gigabytes. In such situations one may wonder about the contents of the
>   folder and its use, and whether it is safe to delete the folder to
>   save memory.

---

**Can I delete the contents of LOST.DIR ?**

> In order to save precious memory space its completely normal to delete
>   the contents of LOST.DIR as it only acts as a recycle bin. You can
>   also delete the LOST.DIR folder itself but it will reappear the next
>   time the system boots up. When your Android system throws up a message
>   saying 'Preparing external SD card' its actually checking the contents
>   of LOST.DIR, and if it fails to locate the directory, it creates one.

---

ref :
[**All you need to know about LOST.DIR folder on Android devices**](http://thesundaycoder.blogspot.com/2014/06/all-you-need-to-know-about-lostdir.html)

Comment: Is it safe to delete? @M4T

Comment: "Use authentic android antivirus software to protect yourself from virus-attack." *LOL* (sorry) To my knowledge, there's not a single virus available for Android. I understand fighting malware – but anti *virus* is … well, placebo. Can't fight what's not there. Besides, that has nothing to do with `LOST.DIR`. // Good answer, apart from that one line. You might wish to fix that up :)

Comment: @Izzy,  you're right.there's not single virus for android OS but, there is many Malwares for this OS.and according to my experiences, anti viruses app on android isnt powerfull for find this malwares.Thank you, edit and updated.;)

Comment: though that's better, the term "antivirus" is definitely 1) misleading (use e.g. "security software" instead), and 2) **completely unrelated to this question** (I'd remove that entire line altogether). // I don't trust any app on Android that calls itself "antivirus" – as that term just plays with the fear of people.

Comment: Now, i think it's better and updated with related reply to this question.